# Why I can't close questions tagged with badge that I have gold badge in it?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, dupehammer

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> It takes 5 close votes to reach the closing threshold (**except for
>   duplicate questions, which can be marked as duplicate with a single
>   vote from a user who has earned a gold tag badge in one of that
>   question's original tags**).

I marked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889120/is-it-possible-to-get-metaphones-for-those-non-english-characters) as *duplicate* and it's still pending close vote. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

The [initial version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26889120/1) of the question was tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and you don't have a gold badge in that tag so you can't [dup-hammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/164200) close it.

The dup-hammer applies:

> ...to any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for

Comment: Thanks, I think this should be changed, is there a request for this feature?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Probably not, the implementation of the dup-hammer was for the original tags not edits to the question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun This pecularity is there to prevent abuse. Otherwise, want to close question quickly? Add tag for which you have gold badge and close. (This may not be the best way to prevent the abuse but there's a reason for it. So if you put in a request for a change, be aware of this.)

Comment: BTW: Is the hidden ultimate zero-revision checked, or the first revision one can see without dev/mod-powers?

Comment: @Deduplicator for answers, it [certainly isn't available publicly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/165773 "see respective feature request declined"); I think it's safe to assume that for questions it isn't either

Comment: @gnat: That was never in doubt.

Answer (score 2):

> has earned a gold tag badge in **one of that question's original tags**

That question was originally tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and not with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), so your gold badge does not have any effect on it.